# cannot refresh listbox from list

Tags: c#, data-binding

I have a c# form which I have ListBox control called lbData
I also have a Class Globals where I have a list of messages
  public static List Messages = new List();

I would like to bind the lbData to the Messages but I don't see the control refreshed with the data even though I can see the messages is >0
This is how I bind it in my form but I don't see it work.

```
        public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ibClient = new EWrapperImpl();
        lbData.DataSource = Globals.Messages;

    }
```

Comment: Use a BindingList instead.

Comment: Are you sure there are items within your Messages list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add lbdata.refresh at the end of your code